# Magento - Remove Billing and Shipping Information when buying downloadable products

Tags: php, magento, paypal, checkout

I run a Magento Shop that has several downloadable products, some come for free with a downloadcode when people buy other products or they get our vouchers from somewhere else.

So there are 2 Scenarios, 1. people buy downloadable products only, pay with paypal, or 2. people download products for free, if they have a voucher.

Its rather annyoing for many people to enter billing information although they are only downloading files as guests and we don't need a billing info.

Did anyone ever come across a way to get rid of the billing info when people are only downloading products? Which means they can actually check out with email only, like its done on pages like bandcamp.com?

Thanks a lot for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to like this.
I don't think it's possible, not within a reasonable cost, to remove the billing address from Magento.
It is deeply embeded in the orders mechanism.
For the shipping address, this should be done out of the box.
If you have only virtual and downloadable products in your order the shipping address and shipping method steps should not appear in the checkout.

But if you insist in doing it I can give you some pointers on where to start.
First you will need to modify the onepagecheckout controller or even better write your own checkout controller that handles your needs.
Then look in the `Mage_Sales` and `Mage_Checkout` modules for the text `getBillingAddress` and `setBillingAddress` and handle the cases when these values can be null.

Here is an example to understand better what I'm talking about.
In the `sendNewOrderEmail` method of the order model there is this

```
$customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
```

You need to change this in case the billing address is null. If it's not null let it work as it does now.

Comment: Hey Marius,
thanks for the, not so promissing, insights ;-) Maybe i'll start hacking with the controller, I'm thinking of creating some sort of dummy customer that will get an address hidden from the real customer.

Comment: @Moses. Told ya you're not going to like it :). I think that it's better to start your own controller instead of hacking the core one. And just to a check in the checkout process. If you have only free downloadable products redirect to your controller. This should be the safest way.

Comment: There's the problem, I have physical, free downloads (via voucher) and payable downloadable products. But I'll focus on the controller, of course I will not change the core.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should be more clear, I don't necessarily need the remove the billing completely. I only need a name and an email address to send the purchase email with the download links. But I need to get rid of Street, Tel, City etc. or set them not-required, but only if all products are downloadable.

Magento already checks whether we need shipping or not based on the shopping cart.

So I would think of something like

1. check in OPC if we need shipping (or alternatively, all products are downloadable)
2. change billing fields to "not-required" or remove them
   2a. If Magento requires an address, maybe set a dummy address hidden from the customer???

cheers Marek